# Allow delete and write with Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Realtime Database. And I have a structure to prevent to many children. I have 2 keys. One for the max(max_people), and one that contains how many children there are (registered_people).

My structure:

[image]

I have the max_people key. This is the max children that can be in the approved key. Registered_people is counting how many childs there in the approved key.

This is my security rule:

```
"registrations": {
     "approved": {
        ".write": "(root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('max_people').val() > root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('registered_people').val())"
}
```

What I do at my firebase rules, is that I check if there not are to many rows. If there are to many I block the writing. This works as expected.

But now the problem, the max_people is for example 20, and the registered_people is also 20. No writes can happen. Because I have declared that. But how can I allow a delete than. Because I want to delete at every moment.

So in short, I want to delete no matter what. And I want to write with my current rule.

Some more information:

I add data to the key with the following code:

```
let data = [
    "full_name": "test",
    "email_addres": "test",
]

Database.database().reference().child("agenda/activitys/" + event + "/registrations/approved").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setValue(data) { (error, ref) in
            print("got from subscribing \(String(describing: error))")
            if((error) != nil){
                completionHandler(Result.failure(ApiError.noMorePlaces))
                return
            } else {
                completionHandler(Result.success("succes \(event)"))
                return
            }
        }
```

Adding works as expected.

And I delete data with the following code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("agenda/activitys/" + event + "/registrations/approved").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).removeValue { (error, ref) in
            if((error) != nil){
                completionHandler(Result.failure(ApiError.unknownError))
                return
            } else {
                completionHandler(Result.success("succes \(event)"))
                return
            }
        }
```

Deleting does not work as expected. I get a permission_denied error when there are for example a max of 20 keys. And that max is fully used (so I have 20 keys with data under the approved child).

Error:

```
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] setValue: or removeValue: at /agenda/activitys/Jumping Fitness/registrations/approved/exCnADF43AdFUzGsi0GllEsZJZY2 failed: permission_denied
```

However deleting works when there a less than the max amount of keys.

Edit:
I have tested the suggested solution on the firebase rules simulator. I got the simulated write error there also.

I think that I have the solution. I delete on the key, so on the rules I need the key also. My solution:

```
"registrations": {
  "approved": {
    ".write":  "(root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('max_people').val() > root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('registered_people').val())",
        "$key" : {
           ".write" : "!newData.exists()"
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data is being deleted, the [`newData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata) variable will be null. So you can check if it exists using the `exists()` method:

```
"registrations": {
     "approved": {
        ".write": "(root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('max_people').val() > root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('registered_people').val()) || !newData.exists()"
}
```

**Update:** After looking at the code you provided, I can see that you do the write operations against the child key. But have in mind that, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade):

> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths.

This means that the write rule under "approved" will overwrite the write rule at "$key". So you should join both rules and keep them under the "$key" rule. Like this:

```
"registrations": {
  "approved": {
        "$key" : {
           ".write" : "(root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('max_people').val() > root.child('/agenda/activitys').child($room_id).child('registered_people').val()) || !newData.exists()"
        }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried that already. I get the permission_denied error. I delete it on the key inside approved. Adding works as expected.

Comment: Please show the code you're using that gives you permission_denied

Comment: When there are 20 values inside nothing can be added as expected. No value can be deleted than. But as soon as there are less than the 20 values the delete works as expected. I am going to sent the code soon.

Comment: Checking `!newData.exists()` is *the* way to test for empty writes. If it doesn't work for you, that depends on what you're writing and the current data. Please update your question to show the exact data and code that reproduce the situation that you're asking about.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I have added more code and examples.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes This works like expected. Thanks for your time and support.